# UnicodeDecodeError while dumping dictionary to file using json dump

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary, created from reading the windows registry where keys of dictionary are registry keys and corresponding values are the values of the same key in dictionary. 
Now, I am trying to dump to a file using `json.dump()`.  But, this gives me two different errors on two different systems. I am unaware about the content of dictionary, but it has unicode values in it. I am opening the file in 'ab' mode to dump data on to same.

```
with open(file_path, 'ab') as fp:
    json.dump(reg_dict, fp)
```

The below errors are observed :-

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

And

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 21: invalid continuation byte
```

Attaching the image for both the errors. I am not sure how can I resolve this, neither why this is coming. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Error in System 1]

[image: Error in System 2]

Comment: Please replace your images with the actual (copy-pasted) traceback, for readability.

Comment: How is `reg_dict` created? Are you reading in another file?

Comment: You've got Unicode in your `reg_dict`—so you need to use `codecs.open()` to open a `"utf_8"` encoded file for writing.

Comment: @Evert, added how the dictionary getting created. And, this is the only trace I have. What else you are looking for ? I guess zooming the image, you can see the traces. Thanks

Comment: @martineau, Do you mean, first I have to use `codecs.open()` before writing it to file? I mean, I am still confused, how to use this ?

Comment: It's clearer to read the traceback as plain text than having to click and zoom in on the messages. Additionally, people with bad sight or other disabilities may not be able to see the actual pictures, but text can be read to them, for example.

Comment: Can you show as code that creates `reg_dict`?

Comment: Yes, I mean you have to use it to open the file for writing. It's more or less like the standard `open()` function, as you can see from its [documention](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).

Comment: @martineau, codecs.open() didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that encoding of data read from the registry not changed. So it is UTF-16. Specifically, UTF-16LE on one system and UTF-16BE on another. This explains the different errors. If my assumption is correct, this may help you:

```
import collections
import io
import json

def decode_dict(data):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return data.decode('utf-16')
    elif isinstance(data, unicode):
        return data
    elif isinstance(data, collections.Mapping):
        return dict(map(decode_dict, data.iteritems()))
    elif isinstance(data, collections.Iterable):
        return type(data)(map(decode_dict, data))
    else:
        return data

with io.open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    fh.write(json.dumps(decode_dict(reg_dict), ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: Even though this worked, still I am getting error like  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 62: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: @PabitraPati Then your input data likely was not UTF-16. Print the first few bytes of your input data, and search around to see if they shed light on what encoding your data actually is.